# UITableView reloading data / refreshing (possible duplication issue)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, reload

I have a `UITableView` in an iPhone application which I am refreshing (by calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the action method for a `UISegmentedControl` dynamically embedded in one of the UITableView cells. The table view is refreshed to update a text value for one of the cells.

However, the following code seems to produce an unwanted side-effect. It appears that each time the UITableView refreshes it creates a new instance of the UISegmentedControl (and possibly the images - I'm not sure) over the existing one(s).

The only reason I notice this is that with each refresh a barely perceptible border starts to form around the UISegmentedControl and the application slows noticeably. I would be extremely grateful for any suggestions/code-solutions to my current predicament.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    // Set up the cell...       


    //populates the personal info section
    if (section == kPersonalInfoAddSection) {

        if (row == kNameRow) {

                    //Other code irrelevant to this question was removed for the sake of clarity
        }
        else if(row == kHeightRow) {

            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableview_height_label.png"];
                    //THIS IS THE TEXT I'M TRYING TO UPDATE
            cell.textLabel.text = [Formatter formatHeightValue:mainUser.heightInMM forZone:self.heightZone];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = REQUIRED_STRING;

        }
    }

    //populates the units section
    if (section == kUnitsSection) {

        if (row == kHeightUnitsRow) {
            NSArray *heightUnitsSegments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:FT_AND_IN_STRING, M_AND_CM_STRING, nil];

            UISegmentedControl *heightUnitControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:heightUnitsSegments];

            CGRect segmentRect = CGRectMake(90, 7, 200, 30);
            [heightUnitControl setFrame:segmentRect];
            //[heightUnitControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
            [heightUnitControl addTarget:self action:@selector(heightSegmentClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            heightUnitControl.tag = kHeightSegmentedControlTag;

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Height:";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"(units)";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:heightUnitControl];

            [heightUnitsSegments release];
            [heightUnitControl release];

        }
        else if(row == kWeightUnitsRow) {

                    //Other code irrelevant to this question was removed for the sake of clarity    

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it is creating a new instance of the UISegmentedControl. It's because you are using a generic cell identifier, @"Cell", then adding the UISegmentedControl each time, never removing it. The cells get cached containing the UISegmentedControl, you retrieve the cached cell and add the control again.

You could use a more specific cell identifier and if cell != nil you know it contains the UISegmentedControl already. Or create a new cell each time that way you're not using a cached cell that already contains the control.

With the image view you just set the cells image view property without adding a new view to the cell so that one is ok, it gets replaced each time.

Since the text you are trying to update doesn't have to do with the UISegmentedControl I think you should be able to use a more specific cell identifier and add the control only on cell creation.

Comment: Even better, create a custom UITableViewCell subclass and use that. There is no reason to restrict yourself to the default cell types if you have more complex needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was just wondering how custom UITableViewCells would assist in this particular circumstance (I'm relatively new to iPhone development).

Also, it seems that using custom cells means that the rounded appearance of the cells in a grouped view disappears (replaced by square conrners).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *arr1=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img1.jpg",@"img2.jpg",nil];
    NSArray *arr2=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img1.jpg",@"img2.jpg",@"img3.jpg",@"img4.jpg",@"img5.jpg",@"img6.jpg",nil];
    NSArray *arr3=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img6.jpg",@"img5.jpg",@"img2.jpg",@"img1.jpg",nil];

    Imgs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arr1,arr2,arr3,nil]];


    NSDictionary *dic1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Ahmedabad",@"Name",@"Picture 5.png",@"Rating",@"Picture 1.png",@"Photo",arr1,@"img",nil];
    NSDictionary *dic2=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Rajkot",@"Name",@"Picture 5.png",@"Rating",@"Picture 2.png",@"Photo",nil];
    NSDictionary *dic3=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Baroda",@"Name",@"Picture 5.png",@"Rating",@"Picture 7.png",@"Photo",nil];

    tblArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dic1,dic2,dic3,nil];
    [myTbl reloadData];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
}



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [tblArray count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *CellIdentifer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[self myCustomCell:CellIdentifer dicToSet:[tblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)myCustomCell:(NSString*)CellIdentifer dicToSet:(NSDictionary*)dicToSet{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer] autorelease];

    UIImageView *imgV=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 40, 40)];
    [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dicToSet valueForKey:@"Photo"]]];
    [cell addSubview:imgV];
    [imgV release];

    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 2, 276, 20)];
    [lbl setText:[dicToSet valueForKey:@"Name"]];
    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18]];
    [lbl release];


    UIImageView *imgV1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 24, 70, 20)];
    [imgV1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dicToSet valueForKey:@"Rating"]]];
    [cell addSubview:imgV1];
    [imgV1 release];


    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    nxtPlcDtl=[[plcFullDtl alloc] initWithNibName:@"plcFullDtl" bundle:nil];
    nxtPlcDtl.dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[tblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    nxtPlcDtl.Imgs = [Imgs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    nxtPlcDtl.comment1 = [comment1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    nxtPlcDtl.vedio = [vedio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nxtPlcDtl animated:YES];



    }
```